How to correctly parse data format Kafka from Azure EventHub
I am new into Kafka and I am trying to read Stream events coming from an Azure EventHub using python but I am not able to correctly extract or parse the data.
kafka_options = {
    # Port 9093 is the EventHubs Kafka port
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": f"{event_hubs_server}:9093",
    "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": sasl_config,
    "kafka.sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url": f"https://login.microsoft.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "subscribe": event_hubs_topic,
    "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "OAUTHBEARER",
    "startingOffsets":"earliest",
    "kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler",
    "maxOffsetsPerTrigger": 1000
}

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**kafka_options).load()

The code above contains a dataframe with the following schema and the content looks like this:
root
|-- key: binary (nullable = true)
|-- value: binary (nullable = true)
|-- topic: string (nullable = true)
|-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
|-- offset: long (nullable = true)
|-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

+--------------------+--------------------+-----+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 key|               value|topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|[64 38 65 61 39 3...|[4B C6 AD 98 A9 1...|prd1 |      106| 79856|2024-03-31 20:18:...|            0|


I tried to parse the binary fields into string using df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") and F.base64(col("value").cast("string")))  but the output is still showing unreadable text.
+--------------------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 key|             value|     topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+--------------------+------------------+----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|[64 38 65 61 39 3...|   Kƭ��zN��{�t�H|prd1      |      106| 79856|2024-03-31 20:18:...|            0|

Please advice me on how to properly parse and extract the data from this format.I have to use Kafka for streaming.

what is the input data you are producing in event hub?Add  the sample records.

You'll need to know how the data is serialized by the Kafka Producer before you can deserialize it

I am not producing the data in the EventHub but it is not produced by Kafka Producer, when consuming the data using EventHub Consumer the data follows a completely different schema.

Can you show that data? Is it JSON? Avro? Protobuf? The Confluent dotnet kafka library supports all those, and only json will be able to be cast to a string by spark. The others will need a custom UDF function to deserialize. I'm not sure what you mean by "completely different" since values will always be binary

Is not json and is not avro, is an IDictionary object from C# that is being load directly into the EventHub Client
